# timestamp within a form

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I currently have a form which inputs patient information into a database. 
I need to obtain the exact date/time of the moment a patient arrives at Accident and Emergency and submit this datetime to the database.

Please find the PHP code below. I don't want the date/time to be displayed within the form, I want it to automatically insert into the database when a patient arrives at A&E. How do I insert datetime into the database?

```
<?php
$arrival = new DateTime();
$arrivalString = $arrival->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use php, you would do something like...

`<input type="hidden" name="datetime" value="<?php echo $arrivalString; ?>" />`

inside your form.

Comment: shall I use a POST method also?

Comment: Whatever you want to do. Just know how to handle in on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
INSERT INTO theTable (timeColumn) VALUES (NOW())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a regular `INSERT` statement. You don't even need to use PHP's datetime functionality since MySQL can take care of this for you.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (arrival_datetime)
VALUES(NOW())
```

or

```
INSERT INTO tablename (arrival_datetime)
VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: This isn't PHP. It's just the SQL you would use with your PHP.

Comment: It has the following error: Fatal error: Function name must be a string.

Comment: I couldn't tell you what that problem is since I can't see your code. You may want to ask a new question posting your PHP code so we can see what you've got.

Comment: If I am using the code I provided above, what would be the value?